# Form a query in Azure Devops to pull all the work items that moved from one state to another

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am looking to form a query in Azure Devops to pull all the work items that moved from one state to another state on or after a particular date, irrespective of what state they are currently in. for example, I would like get all the work items that moved from "Development Completed" to "In QA"  on or after 08-01-2019.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Could you get the work item which moved from one state to anoter with the query which showed in below answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Pull all the work items that moved from one state to another state on
>   or after a particular date, irrespective of what state they are
>   currently in.

Just refer to the below configuration:

[image]

The logic of this query is no matter what state the work item are currently in, query out the work items which was ever changed from Active to Resolved. As you know, it is impossible for the state of one work item was ever in both **Active** and **Resolved** if without any state change. So if you specified these states in query, it will query out the work items which ever moved from Active to Resolved. For the last **Change date**, this does not mean the change date which about state change. It is relevant with this current workitem active date, including link build or other.